# How change cell table color in php based on cell value?

Tags: php, html, css

I just started programming in php.

I made a table that returns values ​​from the database. 
I'm trying to do the following: Change the color of the third column by the value it has.

I was thinking this way, but the values ​​are repeated and the color is not the right way.

Can anyone help me please?

Did you understand my question?

Thank you all. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Code:

```
<table style="width:324px;" border="3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
            <b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Task</font></b>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
            <b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">deadline</font></b>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
            <b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Status</font></b>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num)
{
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Task");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"deadline");
    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");

    ?>
    <tr style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
        <? 
        if($f3==2)
        { 
            // Display RED 
            ?> 
            <td style="background-color:#FF0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
            <? 
        }
        elseif($f3==1)
        { 
            // Display YELLOW 
            ?> 
            <td style="background-color:#0F0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
            <?     
        }
        else
        { 
            ?> 
            <td  style="background-color:#F00;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
            <? 
        } 
        ?> 
    </tr> 
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Result from code:

[image]

SOLVED

Thanks everyone for your help.
Status is a predefined value recorded in the database. Only ranges between 1 and 4 so that the resolution has served @Daniel Andre correctly. 
All responses were valid for me to try to understand a little more php, but it was so simple. 
Again thank you all for your time and for your help.

The final result was:

```
<table style="width:324px;" border="3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>

<td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tarefa</font></b>
</td>
<td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Prazo</font></b>
</td>
<td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Status</font></b>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;while ($i < $num) {
$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"idTarefa");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"PrazoExecucao");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");

?>
<tr style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<!--<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>-->

<?php
  $status_colors = array(1 => '#0000FF', 2 => '#00FF00', 3 => '#FFFF00', 4 => '#FF0000');
?>
<td style="background-color: <?php echo $status_colors[$f3]; ?>;">
</tr> 


<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: can you tell me what is dependency with the last column?

Comment: What is dependence? I apologize but didnt realize your question. 
Can you explain what you wanted to ask please?

Comment: i want to know about the cell, you mention that you want to change the color of cells using php dyanamically?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, I want change only color of third cell dynamically using php. If value is equals to 2 the cell has been red...etc.

Comment: <?php if($f3==2){?>
<td  style="background-color:#F00;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? }else { ?>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<?php } ?>  Try this code with last cell

Comment: remove else section and new this section.and if you have any query then i will be here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the statuses are static (meaning, they don't change, but are a fixed set of statuses), you can make a php array mapping the statuses to colors:

```
<?php
  $status_colors = array(1 => '#FF0', 2 => '#F0F', 3 => '#0FF', 4 => '#0F0');
```

Then, in your td's, use the correct status color:

```
<td style="background-color: <?php echo $status_colors[$f3]; ?>;">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but satus aren't static, they can change.

Comment: This will not work if the `status` value is greater than 3, you will get an error

Comment: Updated to include all the visible statuses from the example, which I thought was obviously an example to get the OP started.

@rpirez, although they change, the value of the status can only be one of a pre-defined list of statuses? If they are truly non-static (they can be anything from "1" to "Bob") or they have a wide range (anything from "1" to "20"), then sure, my answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right, you are displaying 3 columns (yellow, green, red), and only one should be displayed. So, you could try changing these lines:

```
<? 
if($f3==2) { 
    // Display RED 
?> 
<td style="background-color:#FF0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? 
} elseif($f3==1) { 
    // Display YELLOW 
?> 
<td style="background-color:#0F0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<?     
} else { 
?> 
<td  style="background-color:#F00;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? 
} 
?>
```

for these:

```
<? 
switch($f3) {
    case 2: $color="#F00"; break; // Display RED 
    case 1: $color="#FF0"; break; // Display YELLOW 
    default:  $color="#0F0"; break; // Display GREEN 
}
echo '<td style="background-color:'.$color.';"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">'.$f3.'</font></td>';
?>
```

Additional remarks:

- try to switch to PDO / mysqli (you are using deprecated functions).
- note that red id #F00, green #0F0, yellow #FF0. These values were not matching the comments in the provided code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table style="width:324px;" border="3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>

<td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Task</font></b>
</td>
<td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">deadline</font></b>
</td>
<td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Status</font></b>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;while ($i < $num) {
$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Task");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"deadline");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");

?>
<tr style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>


<? 
if($f3==2) { 
    // Display RED 
?> 
<td style="background-color:#FF0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? 
} elseif($f3==1) { 
    // Display YELLOW 
?> 
<td style="background-color:#0F0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<?     
} ?> 

<?php if($f3==2){?>
<td  style="background-color:#F00;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? }else { ?>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<?php } ?> 
</tr> 


<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the columns count if you see. Try this way:

```
<table style="width:324px;" border="3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
            <b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Task</font></b>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
            <b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">deadline</font></b>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
            <b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Status</font></b>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Task");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"deadline");
    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");
?>
    <tr style="background-color:#A4A4A4;">
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<? 
    if($f3==2) { 
        // Display RED 
?> 
        <td style="background-color:#FF0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? 
    } elseif($f3==1) { 
        // Display YELLOW 
?> 
        <td style="background-color:#0F0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<?     
    } else { 
?> 
        <td  style="background-color:#F00;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td> 
<? 
    } 
?> 
    </tr> 
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
</table>
```