# All background color of the cells is the same

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am creating a semester map for studnets. If a course is being taken, the cell color should be yellow. If the course is taken, should be green. If the course is not yet taken, cell color will be red.

I am testing student with id '1', in the table 'course_status' there is a column called 'course_status' with "pending", "in_progress", and "done" only.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM course_status WHERE student_id = 1";
$retval = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($retval);
```

```
if($row['course_status']== 'done') {$status_color = "green";}
if($row['course_status']== 'in_progress') {$status_color= "yellow";}
if($row['course_status']== 'pending') {$status_color= "red";}
```

```
<td style="background-color: <?php echo $status_color; ?>;">CSCI 185 
<td style="background-color: <?php echo $status_color; ?>;">CSCI 385 
<td style="background-color: <?php echo $status_color; ?>;">CSCI 485
```

All of the cell have a background color of green despite the student have not yet taken CSCI 385&485. I just want CSCI 185 to have a green background since its taken already.

Comment: Is this what your code looks like when you are fetching more then 1 record from database?or there are multiple records with `id=1`?

Comment: A) Make a look-up table for this: `[ 'done' => 'green', ... ]` makes the `if` pointless. B) `green` is a string and needs to be quoted. Same for the others. C) You need to turn this into a function and call it for each row. `$status_color` will not magically change for each row there, you must set it each time.

Comment: You will need to loop through the results of your query unless it returns a single row. You will also need to loop through the classes, producing one *td* per row and status.

Comment: multiple records with id=1. Sorry I have tried puting the colors in strings. And how do you create and call a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below  :

```
if($row['course_status']== 'done') {

<td style="background-color:green">something</td>//bg-color will be green

}else if($row['course_status']== 'in_progress'){

<td style="background-color:yellow">something</td>//bg-color will be yellow

} else {
<td style="background-color:red">something</td> //bg-color will be red

}
```

Comment: I literally have hundreds of td cells. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739322/how-change-cell-table-color-in-php-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: that where i got the idea from actually. just wasnt working on my page